# Scala: checking String for only digits behaving strange

Tags: string, scala

I wrote the code, which works as expected, when I apply for entrance *not empty* string with only digits or with not only digits:

```
   def checkDigits(nameOrId: String): Unit = {

      def isAllDigits(x: String) = x forall (c => c.isDigit)

      if (isAllDigits(nameOrId)) print("WITH_ID ")
      else print("WITH_NAME")
  }
```

But when I apply for entrance ""-value, it print no "WITH_NAME", but "WITH_ID ".  So it recognize "" as digit-character!

What am I doing wrong and how could I improve my code?

Comment: From the [ScalaDocs page](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.13.7/scala/collection/StringOps.html#forall(p:Char=%3EBoolean):Boolean): `forall()` returns **true** if this string is empty or the given predicate p holds for all chars of this string... You might try a regex instead: `nameOrId matches "\\d+"`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `forall` method checks whether a test is true for all values in a collection. If there are no values it returns `true`, because all the values pass the test.

For the behaviour you want you need to add an extra test:

```
def isAllDigits(x: String) = x.nonEmpty && x.forall(_.isDigit)
```

Answer (score 0):

The regex alternative is using [matches](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.12.7/scala/collection/immutable/StringOps.html#matches(x$1:String):Boolean) which should match the whole string and match for 1 or more digits.

Note that your method `def checkDigits` returns Unit because you are only printing. To make it return a boolean you can use:

```
def checkDigits(x: String) = x.matches("\\d+")
```